# TinyMCE setActive to false advImage plugin

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have a custom youtube plugin that adds an **image** to my tinyMCE editor and gets replaced with embedded or other code on the server side.

The only thing thats left is when I select the image in the editor, both the advImage icon and my plugin icon get set to active.
I want to set the advimage to non-active. I tried stuff like this:

```
 cm.setActive('image', false);
```

Thanks to [Thariama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/346063/thariama) (see answer below) I know the correct name should be `'image'`. This is called from my youtube plugin `editor_plugin.js` file, and in the console I can see that on selecting an image that code is executed and `image` is the correct target.

How do I set the image plugin to non-active?

See comments below Thariama's answer for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this I let it be for a while because it was not on top of my priority list. Now it was the last thing on my list and because of working more with tinyMCE and it codes I pretty quickly found a solution.

I figured that I needed to go to the root: editor_template.js. This is were image was set to active so I needed to change that.

My images for youtube (and now vimeo as well) have an alt attribbute to tell me if it's a youtube or vimeo video. Now I need to disable either one of those plugins as well.

I have put it on line 1117 after this code (which sets the active state for all img tags.

```
p = getParent('IMG');
if (c = cm.get('image'))
    c.setActive(!co && !!p && n.className.indexOf('mceItem') == -1);
```

And my code:

```
if(ed.selection.getNode())
            if(ed.selection.getNode().getAttribute('alt') === 'videoYoutube' || ed.selection.getNode().getAttribute('alt') === 'videoVimeo') // Get the current selection in the editor and compare
            {
                cm.setDisabled('image', true); // Change disable state
                cm.setActive('image', false); // Change active state state
            }
            else
            {
                cm.setDisabled('image', false);
            }
            if(ed.selection.getNode().getAttribute('alt') === 'videoYoutube')
            {
                cm.setDisabled('addvimeo', true);
            }
            else if(ed.selection.getNode().getAttribute('alt') === 'videoVimeo')
            {
                cm.setDisabled('addyoutube', true);
            }
            else
            {
                cm.setDisabled('addvimeo', false);
                cm.setDisabled('addyoutube', false);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

I will demonstrate the correct way to deactivate a button/control on the html button (the code plugin)

```
var cm = tinymce.get('my_editor_id').controlManager;
cm.get('code').setActive(0); // get the control named 'code'
```

To find out which controls are available you may log this to your console

```
console.log(cm.controls);
```

Comment: if you show me the button on the tinymce demo page (http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php) i can name you the relevant control name necessary to deactivate it

Comment: The relevant control name, according to controls seems to be 'image'. It's just the normal standard (advanced) image plugin that comes with TinyMCE as default. It works when I first set my plugin to active, and then according to your code (cm.get(mypluginname)isActive(0)) set it to non-active it works. But not when I replace code with 'image'....

Comment: Just used setDisabeld instead of setActive, and that shows me that cm.get('image') is correct. Mayby it has something to do with the fact I call this in editor_plugin.js of my youtube plugin? When I call console.log(mc.get('image')) active is always true and tells me the code is fired when I click on an image.